# How can i write custom attribute for functions to do something and redirect in asp .net mvc 5 c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, attributes

I want to write my own authorize attribute (like [authorize] but not in Asp .net Identity) to check in db and if user has not authorize redirect him to somewhere. can anyone help?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Comment: [I downvoted because the question shows no evidence of research effort](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), and because it's [not a real question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create your customAuthorize attribut, for this you can inherit AuthorizeAttribute from asp.net class and make your attribut like:-

(I am using this in my project)

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private User_MasterEntities db = new User_MasterEntities();


    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Home", action = "Restricted" }));//new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);


        if (!authorized)
        {
            // The user is not authenticated
            return false;
        }
        string user = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

        bool isAdmin = IsAppUser(user);

        return isAdmin;

    }
```

and IsAppUser is your function which return it is admin or not from database